# i want make show only 5 records from query then pagination get next 5 till the end

Tags: c#, datagridview, pagination, visual-studio-2017, ms-access-2010

```
    connection.Open();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connection;

            string querytransactions = "select TransactionID as 'الرقم المرجعي' , TransactionDate as 'تاريخ العملية' , TransactionDescription as 'وصف العملية'  , AccountID as ' الحساب' , WithdrawalAmount as ' مسحوبات' , DepositAmount as ' ايرادات' from transactions";

            command.CommandText = querytransactions;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
            DataTable dttransactions = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dttransactions);
            dataGridView3.DataSource = dttransactions;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet() ;

                ds.Clear();
                da.Fill(ds, scr_val, 5);
                connection.Close();
```

i want make show only 5 records from that query in datagridview  i'm using access database then pagination get next 5 till the end i dont need select top 5 from transactions and access db doesnt have limit query so what can i do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Linq to skip records and take the next set of data from the Dataset's datatable of results. You would pass in a skip count and the take count from the front end. Not the most efficient query, but given the limited context available in the question you could do something along the lines of:

```
ds.Tables[0].Select().Skip(5).Take(5);  // skips 5 rows, then selects five after that.
```